# About PRG in JSF 2.0 and View Parameters

Tags: jsf-2

I was trying to understand how to perform PRG on a JSF app using this link
https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/post_redirect_get_and_jsf
but somehow I got confused on three items.

1. From the blog, I see from firebug that it is issuing a 302 and GET redirect when rendering pages instead of the POST method which is a PRG.
   The only changes in the blog is the scope of the bean from being a session scoped to a request scope.  SO does this link suggest that
   all my managed bean be at Request Scope level?  I check my sample app that I am doing and I am heavily using ViewScoped and SessionScope beans.
2. Whats the usefulness of ViewParameters?  Arent that a security problem, supposed I add more query string parameters at the url?
   I am actually finding a use case on where can I used such feature.
3. If the transaction that I am doing will not do any transactional nature such as ADD/EDIT/DELETE, is it still a good practice to just merely use the JSF navigation which is a POST request?  I just wanted to navigate to a new page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So does this link suggest that all my managed bean be at Request Scope level? I check my sample app that I am doing and I am heavily using ViewScoped and SessionScope beans.*

The bean's scope doesn't matter for the PRG itself. It only matters for the lifespan of the data the bean holds. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

---

> *Whats the usefulness of ViewParameters? Arent that a security problem, supposed I add more query string parameters at the url? I am actually finding a use case on where can I used such feature.*

The `includeViewParams` will only include the parameters which you've manually specified in `<f:metadata><f:viewParam>`. It will not include *all* original query parameters. This is not necessary for the PRG itself. Whether to use it or not depends on the concrete functional requirements. The article just shows that *it's possible* to copy all view parameters into the redirect URL, which may be useful/mandatory for some functional requirements. See also [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

---

> *I just wanted to navigate to a new page.*

Use `<h:link>` instead of `<h:commandLink>`.

```
<h:link value="Go to next.xhxml" outcome="next" />
```

See also [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)